# How to add custom fields to a QR code generated with pst-barcode?

Tags: pst-barcode, qrcode

I am currently using the following code to generate a QR code with my contact data. The idea is that scanning the QR code launches the Contacts app with all my contact information, in a way that it can be stored hassle-free. The MWE code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture} (12mm,32mm)
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:Jon Doe;TEL:9836465993;EMAIL:fancyname@fancydomain.com;URL:www.fancydwebsite.com;Institution:Fancy Institution}{eclevel=M width=1.0 height=1.0}{qrcode}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the output my code generates:

[image]

I am including the output this code generates (i.e., a QR code) into a small personal business card. In this business card, I include the following information:

- Full name
- Phone number
- Email address
- Website
- Institution
- Title
- Office number

As you can see, my QR code includes the first four items (i.e., full name, phone number, email address and website), but it does not include the last three items (institution, title and office number). I have tried many things, but I don’t seem to be able to include these three fields into my QR code.

Hence, my question is: ***how can I get my QR code to include all the items listed above (i.e., the ones it already includes plus institution, title and office number)?***

In my iOS contacts app, the field for the office should be an address called “work”, the institution should be the “Company” and the title should be the “Title”. I am not entirely sure whether analogous fields exist in Android, but I suppose so.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: According to Wikipedia `MECARD` supports only a limited number of fields (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MeCard_(QR_code)). Maybe another vCard standard would be more suitable? VCF seems to support more fields (see https://www.iana.org/assignments/vcard-elements/vcard-elements.xhtml).

Comment: vCards can also be encoded as QR codes I think (although I have never tried it), see for example https://www.qr-code-generator.com/solutions/vcard-qr-code/. This is a commercial website but around halfway on the page they actually provide a code example that you may be able to use.

Comment: If you post your comment as an answer, I’ll accept it because I managed to do what I wanted by encoding vCard. If you choose not to post an answer, I’ll either answer it myself or will delete the question.

Comment: There is a dedicated package for business cards that supports qr-codes out of the box: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/businesscard-qrcode

Comment: I wish I had known it earlier… But it’s good to know! Thank you, man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package [qrcode](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/qrcode) works with vcards (using the example linked in Marijns comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}

\begin{document}
\qrcode[level=Q,version=0]{
BEGIN:VCARD
N:Smith;John;
TEL;TYPE=work,VOICE:(111) 555-1212
TEL;TYPE=home,VOICE:(404) 386-1017
TEL;TYPE=fax:(866) 408-1212
EMAIL:smith.j@smithdesigns.com
ORG:Smith Designs LLC
TITLE:Lead Designer
ADR;TYPE=WORK,PREF:;;151 Moore Avenue;Grand Rapids;MI;49503;United States of America
URL:https://www.smithdesigns.com
VERSION:3.0
END:VCARD
}
\end{document}
```

[image]